# Homomorphism between right and left modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a ring. $R$ and its direct sums $R^n$ are right or left module over $R$ itself in the obvious way.

I want to show that

$$
R_R^n\simeq R_R^m\Rightarrow n=m
$$
holds if and only if
$$
_RR^n\simeq\ _RR^m\Rightarrow n=m\;\;\;.
$$
The first idea came to my mind was to show that $R_R^n\simeq\ _RR^n$. From this the conclusion would follow easily.

The problem is: does it make sense to consider a homomorphism between right/left module? How can I define it?

I suppose a generic such morphism would be of the form $\varphi:M_R\to\ _RN$ and it should satisfy $\varphi(m+m')=\varphi(m)+\varphi(m')\;\;\varphi(m\cdot r)=r\cdot\varphi(m)$.

Then if I consider $\varphi:R_R^n\to\ _RR^n\;,\;(r_1,\dots,r_n)\mapsto (r_1,\dots,r_n)$... this is a bijection but not a "right-to-left-module-homomorphism".

How can I do this?

Comment: Hint: http://math.uga.edu/~pete/noncommutativealgebra.pdf Exercise 1.18.

Answer (score 2):

While I can't think of a sensible way to generally define a morphism $M_R \to {}_R N$, here is a hint to help you prove the claim you were originally interested in.

Note that module homomorphisms $R_R^n \to R_R^m$ correspond to $m \times n$ matrices with entries in $R$, if we view the modules as column vectors.  Similarly, module homomorphisms ${}_R R^n \to {}_R R^m$ correspond to $m \times n$ matrices over $R$, this time viewing the modules as spaces of row vectors.  In each case, composition of homomorphisms corresponds to multiplication of matrices, though perhaps in opposite order.

But matrices and their multiplication can be considered independent of whether they act on right modules of row vectors or left modules of column vectors!

(If you need more help, the keyword to search would be "invariant basis number.")